# Setting Up Path Instead of Query in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have what I thought was a very straightforward question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a page that reads in a zip like so:
http://blahblah.com/searchbyzip/?90036

The index.php file there then reads in the zip as a query and using PHP code, the value is manipulated...

I want the user to enter the same URL, but without the question mark. So, they should type and see the following instead:
http://blahblah.com/searchbyzip/90036

I know there is a way to do as a rewrite in .htaccess file. However, I am not very proficient in Apache rewrite. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^searchbyzip/(\d+)$ searchbyzip/?$1
```

If you need any query strings to be passed through then add `[QSA]` at the end of the rule, preceded by a space. It considers a valid "zip" to be any number of digits. If this should be changed in some way let me know.

A version to accept a-z (case-insensitive), numbers, underscores or dashes would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^searchbyzip/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ searchbyzip/?$1
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I had something similar, but not quite that... What if I wanted it to accept non-numerics?

Comment: I added a version to demonstrate an option for that. You could add to the character class but remember to keep the hyphen at the end or escape it.